# Cant find IAM in Service Quotas

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am currently configuring Permission Sets in AWS SSO, and running in the default Quota for managed services. I get the following message:

> You reached the default quota for AWS managed policies. By default, you can attach up to 10 AWS managed policies per permission set. You can request a quota increase for "Managed policies attached to an IAM role" to 20 using Service Quotas.

I am now heading to Service Quotas to search for IAM, however I cant find this Service?
[image]

Any Ideas how to edit the Service Quotas for IAM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to increase the IAM limits from us-east-1:

[image: Management Console]